# PHP file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty works on development machine - PHP 7.2.24 vs 7.4?

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Laravel PHP website on Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk machines where users can upload files. This worked fine until I found out that the current setup (running PHP 7.2 running on 64bit Amazon Linux) is deprecated. My dev server is also running PHP 7.2.

I then duplicated my setup using a new environment, PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2. Suddenly, I get this error when I want to save files to S3:

```
file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
```

Using

```
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));
```

This still works on the old machine and on my dev machine. When I examine the $file object, I see that it is saved under /tmp on my old (dev)server but it's empty except the filename on the new PHP 7.4 server

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1559 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "file.csv"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/var/app/current/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Is this a PHP-related issue? Or perhaps the new ELB machines do not allow for files written in /tmp?

Comment: Since you're using Beanstalk have you tried to look for errors in Cloudwatch?

Comment: check out whether php user has the permission to write file in /tmp--using ls -l command in your linux terminal

Answer (score 0):

As always, I only get the best ideas after I post to StackOverflow. I found out that small files do get processed. So that was an aha moment. I forgot I removed some extensions that also change the max upload size for PHP. Here is the relevant code:

in the root folder of the PHP project, make a folder `.ebextensions`

and create  `instance.config` with the following content

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 128M
      post_max_size = 256M
      memory_limit = 512M
```